# Inherit from generic plantuml

Tags: plantuml

is there a way to visualize `ServerManagerNotification`.
I want to show that ServerManagerNotification extends a specific implementation (`IServerManagerNotificationCallback`) of `NotifyBase` like in the code below.

I want to visualize exacply that:

```js
export class ServerManagerNotification extends NotifiesBase<IServerManagerNotificationCallback> {
...
```

NotifiesBase:

```js
export abstract class NotifiesBase<T extends INotifyBase> extends Set<T> {
...
```

Screenshot:
[image]

Current plantuml:

```
@startuml Obeserver in action

namespace ObserverStub {

    interface INotificationContext
    INotificationContext : notifyName: string;
    note right of INotificationContext::notifyName {
        Enforces a valid name for every notifier
        (logging&debugging experience)
    }

    abstract class NotifiesBase<T extends INotificationContext> extends Set
    NotifiesBase *- INotificationContext
    NotifiesBase : +addNotify(callback: T): void;
    note left of NotifiesBase::addNotify
        Adds a notify to the notify list
    end note
    NotifiesBase : +removeNotify(callback: T): number;
    note left of NotifiesBase::removeNotify {
        Removes a notify from the notifiers list
        @returns the number of notifiers left aftering removing
    }
    NotifiesBase : {abstract} getLogData(): ILogData;
    note left of NotifiesBase::getLogData {
        Provides meta information from the implementer
    }
    NotifiesBase : #log(message: string): void;
    note left of NotifiesBase::log {
        Log notify calles
    }
}

namespace Publisher {
    interface IServerManagerNotificationCallback {
        onServerConnect(serverSession: IServerSession): void;
        onServerDisconnect(serverSession: IServerSession): void;
    }
    class ServerManagerNotification extends ObserverStub.NotifiesBase
    ServerManagerNotification o- IServerManagerNotificationCallback

    interface IServerManager {
        addServerManagerNotify(callback: IServerManagerNotificationCallback): void;
        removeServerManagerNotify(callback: IServerManagerNotificationCallback): void;
    }

    class ServerManager implements IServerManager {
        +addServerManagerNotify(callback: IServerManagerNotificationCallback): void;
        +removeServerManagerNotify(callback: IServerManagerNotificationCallback): void;
    }
    ServerManager : notifies: ServerManagerNotification
    ServerManager *- ServerManagerNotification
}

namespace Subscriber {
    class VoiceServiceManager implements Publisher.IServerManagerNotificationCallback {
        +onServerConnect(serverSession: IServerSession): void;
        +onServerDisconnect(serverSession: IServerSession): void;
    }
}

@enduml
```

**Update:** Even if its technically wrong I ended up with this

[image]